# SQL Select - optional date check in where clause

Tags: sql, date, null, where-clause, sqlanywhere

I have a **view** in sqlanywhere11 with the following structure (dates in dd-mm-yyyy format):

`ID,    VALID_FROM,    VALID_UNTIL,    SOME_VALUE

1,     01-01-2013,    01-02-2013     1

1,     02-02-2013,    01-03-2013     2

1,     02-03-2013,    01-04-2013     3

1,     null,           null          3`

So there are multiple entries with the same id but different dates, and dates may also be null. 
Now I need a query that selects only the entry with the current date between **VALID_FROM** and **VALID_UNTIL** or the one with the **null** date if the current date is not in any of the valid ranges.
I tried the following query:

`SELECT * FROM MYVIEW WHERE VALID_FROM IS NULL OR getdate() BETWEEN VALID_FROM AND VALID_UNTIL;`

But this will not work because if there is a **null** row, it will always be selected, even if there is another row with a valid date range.

Is it possible to create a SELECT query that finds the right rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just do a [SELECT TOP 1] and order it so the null would be last?

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM MYVIEW 
WHERE VALID_FROM IS NULL OR getdate() BETWEEN VALID_FROM AND VALID_UNTIL
ORDER BY CASE WHEN VALID_FROM IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're explicitly selecting the null rows with the

```
VALID_FROM IS NULL
```

I'd suggest trying something like:

```
SELECT * FROM MYVIEW WHERE getdate() BETWEEN VALID_FROM AND VALID_UNTIL;
```

Or maybe I've missread the question ...

Comment: But then I would never get the null row. I want to get the null row, if no row with valid date range exists.

Comment: Yeah I misread the question, sorry. @tclark333 answer should do the trick nicely.